Radio Button text UI for some option not showing correct
We took a radio group in xml  layout, and adding radio button to it via programmatically. But problem is for samsung device the UI of some radio button text is not showing in proper. Don't know what is issue cause for all other device its showing correct only. Below I have attached UI screen shot & Code for adding radio button to radio group. Any help would appreciate.
//Samsung image result
enter image description here
//Code for Adding radio button to Radio group via programmatically
 private fun addRadioButtons() {
        for (option in questions.options) {
            val rdbtn = RadioButton(mContext)
            rdbtn.id = View.generateViewId()
            rdbtn.text = option.value.toString().trim()
            rdbtn.textSize = 20f
            rdbtn.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            rdbtn.tag = option
            rdbtn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#312E7F"))
            radioGroup?.addView(rdbtn)


        }
    }

//This is xml layout
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clQuestion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_rounded_corner_bg"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/size_14dp"
        android:visibility="visible">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/questionText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/radioGroup"
            android:textColor="@color/in_video_question_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_12sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_14dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/submitButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/questionText"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/questionText">

        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/submitButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/radioGroup"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btSkip"
            android:background="@drawable/ok_btn"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/in_video_submit_btn_color"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_2dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:padding="@dimen/size_4dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btSkip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/radioGroup"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/submitButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9"
            android:background="@drawable/ok_btn"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/in_video_submit_btn_color"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_2dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Skip"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_10sp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_4dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/size_14dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/size_14dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clFeedback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_min="@dimen/size_275dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="@dimen/size_200dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_rounded_corner_bg"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/size_14dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFeedback1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/in_video_question_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_22sp"
            android:text="Oh Oh!"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFeedback2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvFeedback1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btOkay"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/in_video_question_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_14sp"
            android:text="That’s incorrect, but let's proceed anyway."
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btOkay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvFeedback2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9"
            android:background="@drawable/ok_btn"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/in_video_submit_btn_color"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Okay"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_13sp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_4dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/size_14dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/size_14dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clFeedbackQuestionType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_min="@dimen/size_275dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="@dimen/size_200dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_rounded_corner_bg"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/size_14dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFeedbackQuestion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_14dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_12sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
            />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guildLine1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guildLine2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.67"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llEmojies"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guildLine1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guildLine2"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
            android:gravity="center">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/clVeryPoor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivVeryPoor"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_40dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/very_poor"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvVeryPoor"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvVeryPoor"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Very Poor"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_9sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/border1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_5dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivVeryPoor"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivVeryPoor"/>
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/border1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_4dp"
                    android:background="#FF3632"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/clPoor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivPoor"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_40dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/poor"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvPoor"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPoor"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Poor"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_9sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/border2"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_5dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/border2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_4dp"
                    android:background="#FF6D00"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/clAverage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivAverage"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_40dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/average"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvAverage"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAverage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Average"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_9sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/border3"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_5dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivAverage"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivAverage"/>
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/border3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_4dp"
                    android:background="#FFC100"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/clGood"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivGood"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_40dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/good"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvGood"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvGood"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Good"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_9sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/border4"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_5dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/border4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_4dp"
                    android:background="#C8DC18"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/clExcellent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivExcellent"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_40dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/excellent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvExcellent"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvExcellent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Excellent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_9sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/border5"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_5dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivExcellent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivExcellent"/>
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/border5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_4dp"
                    android:background="#6BC63B"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_1by2dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.95"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llEmojies"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"
            android:background="#B6B6B6"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btSubmit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btSkipFeedback"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9"
            android:background="@drawable/ok_btn"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/in_video_submit_btn_color"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_10sp"
            android:padding="@dimen/size_4dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btSkipFeedback"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btSubmit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9"
            android:background="@drawable/ok_btn"
            android:text="Skip"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_10sp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_4dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/size_14dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/size_14dp"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


I'm guessing that it's the Gravity property that's causing it. Try to use Gravity.START or any other Gravity values and see if something changes.
rdbtn.gravity = Gravity.START

Based on the screenshot you provided, it seems that the third radio button has more than one line of text so you see the obvious effects of gravity. For those radio buttons that have only one line of text, the gravity is not that obvious.

I removed that rdbtn.gravity = Gravity.CENTER, then it worked. But Yes, its gravity issue.
